# Multiple ORDER statement MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Is it possible to make something like this in MySQL

```
if(`column` = 0) ORDER BY `id` DESC
if(`column` = 1) ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

This is what I just tried but it's not working

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `table`
WHERE 
    1
ORDER BY
    CASE `column` = 0 THEN `table`.`id` DESC,
    CASE `column` = 1 THEN `table`.`date` ASC
```

Comment: I don't get how this makes sense.  What if some rows are `0` and some rows are `1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is as two separate statements:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN `column` = 0 THEN `table`.`id` END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN `column` = 1 THEN `table`.`date` END) ASC
```

However, if `column` is a column in the data and not a constant, I'm not quite sure what you want.  Normally `id`s and `date`s would not be compatible.  One would appear before the other, probably.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `WHEN`:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
  `table`
WHERE 
  1
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN `column` = 0 THEN `table`.`id` DESC END,
  CASE WHEN `column` = 1 THEN `table`.`date` ASC END
```